# Forecast of a large time-series does not recognise daily patterns. What could be a solution?

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I have a large time-series accounting for the hourly electricity demand of a country in a 10 year time period (2006 - 2015). Based on this, I want to forecast future values up until the year 2020 on an hourly basis.

I've tried several functions based on some research and ended up with the `stl` model. The results I receive look like the following:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2ZGf.png)

As you can see, the time-series of the electricity demand shows a daily pattern with a local peak in the morning and one in the evening hours respectively. However, the forecasted profile (here in blue) does not show this characteristic and I seem to struggle on how to appropriately find a model/ or fit the time-series to account for this characteristic.

In the following, I have provided you my code to give you a better understanding of what I actually did.

```
## Import Dummy Data
inputfile <- "C:/xxx/ForecastingTool/01_Testing/ConsumptionDataPT2006_2015/ConsumptionData.csv"
mygenerationdata <- read.csv(inputfile)

mygenerationdata$ConsumptionProfile <- ts(mygenerationdata$ConsumptionProfile, start = c(2006,1), frequency = 8764)

## Estimating model
fit.myprofile <- stl(mygenerationdata$ConsumptionProfile, s.window = "periodic", robust = "TRUE")
summary(fit.myprofile)

# Forecasting
## Alternative 1 stl + forecast
fit.forecast <- forecast(fit.myprofile, method="naive", h = 500)
plot(forecast(fit.myprofile, method="naive", h = 500), include = 500)
```

So in a nutshell, what can I do to fit the model appropriately to account for the daily pattern of the electricity profile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your recommendation, I found a function msts that allowed me to account for the different seasonalities in my time-series. I modified the following line of my previous code:

```
mygenerationdata$ConsumptionProfile <- 
  ts(mygenerationdata$ConsumptionProfile, start = c(2006,1), frequency = 8764);
```

using:

```
mygenerationdata$ConsumptionProfile <-
  msts(mygenerationdata$ConsumptionProfile,
       start = c(2006,1),
       seasonal.periods = c(24, 168, 730.5, 8764.8),
       ts.frequency = 8764.8)
```

and got proper results:
[image: Forecasting of multi-seasonal time-series]

Answer (score 0):

Your data has multiple seasonalities: there is definitely a daily trend, but probably also a weekly and annual trend. Currently, your `ts` object has a frequency of 8764, which means you are only capturing the annual trend. In order to account for daily seasonality, you can set the frequency to 24 (ignoring weekly and annual trends in favor of daily trends), or you can fit a model with multiple seasonalities. The second option is probably going to deliver better results. For further reading, I'd advice the book Forecasting by Rob Hyndman, specifically [chapter 11](https://otexts.com/fpp2/complexseasonality.html#complexseasonality), which suggests several methods for working with complex seasonalities. I'd also advice you to look into the `prophet` package.

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast reply! I've already read a lot about and of Rob Hyndman but could not find the solution for my 'problem'. I will take a look at the book and the prophet package you proposed. Thanks a lot!

Comment: If the information I provided was helpful, would you mind marking the question as answered? If you have further questions, let me know what more information you need or perhaps open a new question.

Comment: Based on your recommendation, I found a function `msts` that allowed me to account for the different seasonalities in my time-series. I modified the following line of my previous code: `mygenerationdata$ConsumptionProfile <- ts(mygenerationdata$ConsumptionProfile, start = c(2006,1), frequency = 8764)`; using: `mygenerationdata$ConsumptionProfile <- msts(mygenerationdata$ConsumptionProfile, start = c(2006,1), seasonal.periods = c(24, 168, 730.5, 8764.8),ts.frequency = 8764.8)` and got proper results!